# A book about the the protagonist being able to bodily trans-locate which is referred to specifically as a 'Jaunt' or 'jaunting'

Tags: story-identification, books

I am looking to buy a book that my father read as a boy, for his next birthday.  I know very little about it except the protagonist is able to bodily trans-locate in a manner referred to specifically as a 'Jaunt' or 'jaunting'.  My father's childhood was in the late 1930's through the 40's, so I would guess this is relatively early SciFi.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I was under the impression that VTC duplicate was how one went about trying to get that confirmation.  I'm open to being corrected about that?

Comment: @gowenfawr: We require an accepted (even if by comment) answer for both source and destination.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots so one posts a link to the suspected dupe, either as an answer or as a comment, and only after the OP confirms that's the answer does the VTC process start?

Comment: That's correct.  Usually one of the gold badgers will close it via dupe hammer.

Comment: Either I just learned something, or scifi does it differently than security, or both :)

Comment: Our "story-identification" tags work that way. Other types of questions do not. It basically has to do with an acknowledgment that knowledge of whether it's a correct answer is intensely personal, and even items that seem very alike may be different.

Comment: And, accepted now.

Comment: Just as an observation or future readers, "jaunting" as teleportation was also used in the various incarnations of The Tomorrow People, from the 70s to the 90s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This term is used extensively in Alfred Bester's "Tiger, Tiger" aka "[The Stars My Destination](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1117)" to refer to teleportation.

> By the first decade of the twenty-fifth century the principles of
> jaunting were established and the first school was opened by Charles
> Fort Jaunte himself, then fifty-seven, immortalized, and ashamed to
> admit that he had never dared jaunte again.

Comment: 1957 is a bit further than what OP thought but memory's ticky sometimes

Comment: Thank you - I'm sure this must be it.