# Novel about a guy who travels through portals to bring back alien technology (jaunt?)

Tags: story-identification, novel, soft-sci-fi

A while back I had read a Goodreads description of a novel that I have forgotten the name of. It was about a guy having discussions with his therapist about his profession which is to jump through a portal to go to some far away location and bring back alien tech to sell on the black market or something like that. This guy is supposed to be an unreliable narrator and he has done some shady stuff. I think going through the portal was called a "jaunt" maybe.

Comment: Possibly Gateway, by Frederik Pohl... not 'jumping through portals' but rather 'boarding an alien spaceship preprogrammed on FTL jumps', but definitely talking to therapist and IIRC some uncertainty about whether what he's saying is entirely accurate.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to rollback your edit, as future readers might be remembering the same keywords. It's not a problem if story-ID questions contain misremembered parts :)

Comment: Continuing the "our story-ID policies aren't instinctive" comment from above, the dupe-closure isn't a punition or whatever, it's just that in order to map the story-ID questions together, [we close as duplicates when both are accepted, per policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7067/98028), even if the questions don't look similar. Once again, that doesn't mean there's any problem with your question :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possibly a better one than *The Stars My Destination* <sup>1</sup>, and a more fitting Goodreads review, *Gateway* (1977) by Frederik Pohl. Specifically, [this review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1258864469):

> **Half the book takes place during analysis sessions with Robinette Broadhead and his computerized therapist**. Listening in on another person’s therapy sessions is about as interesting as having someone tell you their dreams. The other half is Broadhead’s story of his life as a prospector on Gateway. Gateway is an asteroid honeycombed with tunnels left by the Heechee, an advanced race that inhabited the universe five hundred thousand years ago. On Gateway they left behind a fleet of their spacecraft, ships that will still travel to their preprogrammed destinations when you push the right button. **Fortunes can be made on these trips if one discovers traces of Heechee technology that can be adapted for human use. Broadhead has made one**. But most flights discover nothing, return with their crews dead of starvation or disease, or never return at all.

Check:

- it's on Goodreads, I guess
- therapist is involved
- allusion to alien tech and money that can be made out of it, though that's a recurring theme

Doesn't quite check: per Wikipedia there doesn't seem to be teleportation, nor "jaunt", but the title may be misleading ("gateway"). Since the protagonist does go to Gateway...

---

Found with the Google query `science fiction therapist steal alien tech site:goodreads.com/book`.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>For the record, I had actually posted *The Stars My Destination* (1955) as a first answer since I remembered it from [A book about the the protagonist being able to bodily trans-locate which is referred to specifically as a 'Jaunt' or 'jaunting'](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/202765/), but then deleted it as it wasn't a match with the therapist and all. Hence this introduction sentence.</sub>

Comment: I had mistakenly attributed the term Jaunt from The Stars My Destination to this novel. This is the novel I was looking for, both of these novels are in my to-read list and I had got them a little mixed up. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: You're welcome, enjoy the read :) *(and not the re-read, as I said in a previous comment...)*