A story about a personal mode of teleportation, called "jaunting," possibly in Analog or Amazing Stories
In the 50's, I think, I read a story about a scientist, last name Jaunt, who caught himself on fire and found himself outside his lab in the hall next to a fire extinguisher.
Further experimentation, placing him in fatal situations, led to the existence on something in the brain whereby anyone could teleport anywhere they have been before.

Interesting, in the 1970s BBC Series The Tomorrow People they used jaunting to describe their teleporting ability.

This is almost definitely Bester's The Stars My Destination, serialized in Galaxy in 1956.
Quoting from the introduction to the first installment (Galaxy, October 1956):

"Where are the new frontiers?" the Romantics cried, unaware that the frontier of the mind had opened in a laboratory on Callisto at the turn of the 24th century. A researcher named Jaunte set fire to his bench and himself (accidentally) and let out a yell for help, with particular reference to a fire extinguisher. Who so surprised as Jaunte and his colleagues when he found himself standing alongside said extinguisher, seventy feet removed from his lab bench?
They put Jaunte out and went into the whys and wherefores of his instantaneous seventy-foot journey. Teleportation—the transportation of oneself through space by an effort of the mind alone—had long been a theoretical concept, and there were a few hundred badly documented proofs that it had happened in the past. This was the first time that it had ever taken place before professional observers.


If so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86241/sole-survivor-of-attack-on-mining-vessel-abandoned-by-his-employer-has-ability

@FuzzyBoots True enough, but none of the existing duplicate answers covered the details in the question.

Eyeh, but policy.

@FuzzyBoots Not saying it won't get closed, just saying it was worth posting an answer anyway.

Ah. No, I'm totally in agreement that posting an answer was correct. :-D Sorry for any confusion there. I personally really don't like the "Dupe close from comments" that some people seem to be suggesting. People deserve credit for their answers, even when it is a duplicate situation, and as you say, it allows addressing differing points.

Stephen King also wrote a story called "The Jaunt", borrowing the title and concept from Bester's story. King's teleportation was achieved through technology, and his story demonstrated how something could go wrong with the process. King's 'Jaunts' seemed eternal to the travelers, unless said travelers were asleep.

@DavidW this one asks about the term at least https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/202765/28516

Blue Jaunt: that was teleporting to nowhere, to commit suicide.

In Britain, the novel was originally published as Tiger, Tiger, but the recent Gollancz SF Masterworks edition restored the original title.

@KlausÆ.Mogensen The question mentions reading it in a magazine, and TSMD was the title it was serialized under.

@DavidW I realize that! I just wanted to make it easier for the OP to find the book. :-)
